# bootstrap4 bug? reboot.css overriding core Bootstrap (button link text black)

Tags: bootstrap-4

See the following snippet, taken from the Bootstrap [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template) (I only removed the js since I don't need it)

I came from bootstrap3, I never really used the 4, but the button text should be white, not black... is this a bug?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <h1>Hello word!</h1>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary">Let's go ></a> </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `role="button"` and some `href` when using an `a` tag instead of `button`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <h1>Hello word!</h1>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="#">Let's go ></a> </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

From [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#button-tags):

> When using button classes on  elements that are used to trigger
>   in-page functionality (like collapsing content), rather than linking
>   to new pages or sections within the current page, these links should
>   be given a role="button" to appropriately convey their purpose to
>   assistive technologies such as screen readers.